# Как импортировать виртуальную машину с VirtualBox на ESXi

Tags: virtualbox, vmware, virtual

Нужно установить уже готовый образ виртуальный машины созданный с помощью VirtualBox на VMware ESXi. Нашел хорошую инструкцию http://www.baconapplications.com/export-a-virtualbox-machine-to-vmware/, но возникает проблема с ошибкой "Details: Line 25: Unsupported hardware family 'virtualbox-2.2'.".", в статье есть решение этой проблемы, говорится, что необходимо изменить данные в файле .ovf
[image: виртуальная машина]
И у меня не получается выполнить данный пункт так как в 7zip появляется ошибка, что невозможно изменить файл. Мне кажется что это потому, что у меня нет прав доступа на изменения данных в архиве, хотя являюсь локальным админом и создателем файла.
Помогите пожалуйста решить данную проблему или подскажите как по другому можно установить уже созданную машину на ESXi.

Comment: Классический вариант распаковать, изменить, упаковать обратно чем не подходит?

Comment: При таком варианте появляется ошибка "Did not find OVF file at beginning of OVA archive" при попытки установить ova в VMware vSphere Client

Comment: Убедиться, что упаковал без папки. При упаковке сделать архив того же вида, что был (тип сжатия, непрерывность), архиватору передать 3 имени файла, а не паковать папку.

Comment: А можно тогда подсказать программу, которая позволит узнать какого вида архив ova? В 7zip я подобного функционала не наблюдал.

Comment: я архивирую файлы в tar архив, после чего переименовываю  в .ova, в  7zip для формата tar нет никаких настроек.

Comment: Тип `tar` - всё верно, 7Zip это показывает. Упакуй файлы в правильном порядке.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Я решил эту проблему следующим образом:

1.экспортируем виртуальную машину c VirtualBox в формате **ova**(например, test.ova).

2.Качаем программу Ovftool https://code.vmware.com/web/dp/tool/ovf/4.1.0.

Конвертируем виртуальную машину в формате ova.

`ovftool.exe  --lax test.ova result.ovf`

В результате конвертации получаем три файла:

1. result.ovf
2. result.mf
3. result-disk1.vmdk

   3. В файле result.ovf делаем следующие изменения:

3.1 вместо

`<vssd:VirtualSystemType>virtualbox-2.2</vssd:VirtualSystemType>`

прописываем

```
 `<vssd:VirtualSystemType>vmx-07</vssd:VirtualSystemType>`
```

Чтобы не было ошибки

`"Details: Line 25: Unsupported hardware family 'virtualbox-2.2'."`

3.2 удаляем следующие строчки

```
<Item>
        <rasd:AddressOnParent>3</rasd:AddressOnParent>
        <rasd:AutomaticAllocation>false</rasd:AutomaticAllocation>
        <rasd:Caption>sound</rasd:Caption>
        <rasd:Description>Sound Card</rasd:Description>
        <rasd:ElementName>sound</rasd:ElementName>
        <rasd:InstanceID>6</rasd:InstanceID>
        <rasd:ResourceSubType>ensoniq1371</rasd:ResourceSubType>
        <rasd:ResourceType>35</rasd:ResourceType>
    </Item>
```

Иначе у меня была следующая ошибка `the ovf package requires unsupported hardware`

4.Удаляем result.mf, иначе будет ошибка

```
"Failed to deploy OVF package: file myVm.vmdk fails integrity check and may have been corrupted during transfer"
```

5.Переходим в VNware Client, находим Deploy OVF tool, выбираем result.ovf и переносим виртуальную машину.

Полезные ссылки:

- http://www.baconapplications.com/export-a-virtualbox-machine-to-vmware/
- https://itdraft.ru/2017/10/05/perenos-virtual-noj-mashiny-iz-virtualbox-v-esxi/
- https://serverfault.com/questions/859741/deploy-ovf-package-fails/861497